# TWITTER API CREATING MEDIA METADATA

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to create a program that posts text with image, but I'm facing a problem on create media metadata. Twitter seems to reject and return this message "Could not authenticate you." with error code 32, and statusCode: 401.

Bellow is my code.

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 1;
const twit = require('twit');
const ApiKey ="API";
const ApiSecret = "API SECRET";
const AccessToken = "TOKEN";
const AccessTokenSecret = "TOKEN SECRET";
const fs = require("fs");

const files = ['FxCvZrAXgAUFXGS.png'];
const status = 'Mrn';

const T = new twit({
  consumer_key:ApiKey, consumer_secret:ApiSecret,
  access_token:AccessToken, access_token_secret:AccessTokenSecret,
  timeout_ms:60*1000, strictSSL:true,
});


//run the test function 
function runpost(img, title){
  try{
    var b64content = fs.readFileSync(img, { encoding: 'base64' });
    T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
      // now we can assign alt text to the media, for use by screen readers and
      // other text-based presentations and interpreters
      var mediaIdStr = data.media_id_string;
      var altText = title;
      var meta_params = {media_id: mediaIdStr, alt_text: { text: altText }};
      
      T.post('media/metadata/create', meta_params, function (err, data, response) {
        if(err) throw err;
        // now we can reference the media and post a tweet (media will attach to the tweet)
        var params = { status: `${title}`, media_ids: [mediaIdStr] }
        T.post('statuses/update', params, function (err, data, response) { console.log(data); });
      });
    });
  }
  catch(e){console.log(`The error is: ${e}`);}
}

runpost(`IMAGE_PATH/${files[0]}`, "Hello! Twitter");
```

Response:

```
{
  statusCode: 401,
  twitterReply: '{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}',
  code: 32,
  allErrors: [ { code: 32, message: 'Could not authenticate you.' } ]
}
```

Please hlep, Thanks in advance!